# With cout, how to convert char into an address/reference (?) to a variable?

Tags: c++, matrix, char, type-conversion, cout

so basically my issue is the following:

I have a function that randomly generates a 3x3 matrix which is filled with random elements ranging from number 1 to number 7 (integers).

```
int aleatoriu ()

    {
        int rezultat;
        rezultat = rand() % 7 +1;
        return rezultat;
    }

void popmatrice ()

    {
        int i, j;
        for (i=1;i<=3;i++)
            for (j=1;j<=3;j++)
               m[i][j]=aleatoriu();
    }
```

I also have a function which displays a matrix where, for each of the elements in the matrix before, it displays 96 + that element as a character (i.e. showing a for 1, b for 2, etc.)

```
char fachar (int numar)

{
    char rezultat;
    rezultat=numar+96;
    return rezultat;
}

void afmatricelit ()

    {
        int i, j;
        for (i=1;i<=3;i++)
            {
                for (j=1;j<=3;j++)
                    cout<<fachar(m[i][j])<<" ";
                cout<<endl;
            }
    }
```

I also have 7 char variables globally defined. An example:

```
char a = '$';
char b[]="BAR";
```

..and so on up to the variable char g;

I would like to have a function which displays my matrix in that instead of displaying the corresponding letter for each number (i.e 1 - a, 2 - b, 3 - c, etc.), displays the actual character stored in variable a (corresponding to number 1 i.e. letter a), the character(s) stored in variable b (corresponding to number 2 i.e. letter b) and so on.

Is there any way to do this with just using cout? I guess my problem is with the datatype of what I'm trying to display - if I could somehow get the code to compile into the equivalent of cout<

Comment: Instead of `result = number + 96;` you should write `result = number + '0';`. It's a lot easier to read (and is more portable).

Comment: Also, can you give us an example of a possible input and output for it? It's a bit hard to understand what exactly you're asking about.

Comment: `cout<<fachar(m[i][j])<<" ";` -> `cout << static_cast<char>(m[i][j])` or `cout << (char) m[i][j]`

Comment: HolyBlackCat: As it is, my void afmatricelit () function displays a for the matrix element 1, b for matrix element 2 and so on. Instead, I want it to display the data stored in variable a for the matrix element 1, the data stored in variable b for the matrix element 2, and so on. With char a = '$' and char b[]="BAR" , I would want it to display $ when encountering the matrix element 1, BAR when encountering matrix element 2 and so on.

Comment: @chopperbawss still no idea what you mean, are you trying to implement a matrix where the different elements can hold different datatypes?

Comment: @George: if i have char a = 'x' and char b = 'a', how would I go from cout<<b displaying 'a' to cout<<b displaying the data stored in variable a (in this case, 'x')? As in, what would I modify?

Comment: first element in an array is m[0] not m[1] and the last one is m[n - 1] not m[n]

Answer (score 3):

Don't name your variables `a` to `g` - put the names in an array instead, and index the array.

```
std::string fachar (int numar)
{
    std::string text[7] = { "$", "BAR", .... };
    if (numar < 1 || 7 < numar)
       throw std::out_of_range("invalid numar");
    return text[numar-1];
}
```

---

Also, as noted in the comments above, array indices run for **0** to one less than the array size.  Thus your matrix loops should look like:

```
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
                    cout << fachar(m[i][j]) << ' ';
                cout<<endl;
            }
```

In fact, you might want to fill your matrix with values in the range [0, 6].  It would simplify `fachar`.